# Said + (to me) in Reported Speech

Tags: reported-speech

Group A

1. He said he would be late.
2. He said to me he would late.

Group B (as in a request)

1. He said to open the door.
2. He said to me to open the door.

As I understand it, the second sentence in group B is incorrect, but that the second sentence in group A is correct. Am I right about this? Could someone explain why this is true? Is it possible to use 'said to + object' in reported speech?

Comment: 2B isn't idiomatic. 2A doesn't necessarily mean "he" specifically instructed *the speaker* to open the door - it would often be equivalent to *The door should (now) be opened* without specifying ***who*** should do it. Consequently that format is often used when the speaker is reporting back to others, where it means *He said that **we / one of us** should open the door*, rather than a direct instruction to the speaker to do this himself.

Comment: Native speakers would normally say *He **told** me he would be late* for context 1B.

Comment: Is it correct to say that 'said to + object' cannot be used in reported speech requests @ FumbleFingers

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that. Note that I didn't say 2B is *invalid* - I said it's *not idiomatic*. We'd nearly always use transitive ***told me*** rather than intransitive+preposition ***said to me*** if what follows is an ***infinitive-based*** complement *(He **told** me **to go**)*. But there are many different subclasses of "object" in this context, and there's wide variation in what forms different native Anglophones find "acceptable" (separately in formal written or relaxed conversational contexts).